# .NET MAUI Entry Control Color When Disabled

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

In the dark theme on Android 14 (and earlier), the text in Entry controls have have been disabled via IsEnabled = False, is gray in color.  This is very hard to read on a black background. I haven't found a way to access this color in the disabled state. Is it possible to change this programmatically if not in XAML?

```
<Entry x:Name="TextEditor"
    IsEnabled="False"
    Keyboard="Plain"
    TextTransform="Uppercase"
    MinimumWidthRequest="140"
    MaxLength="12"
    ReturnType="Next"
    Text="{Binding SomeVar}"/>
```

I've used AppThemeBinding but there doesn't seem to be a property for Entry that I can apply it to.

I tried changing the TextColor property to use other colors than the defaults in the hopes that when IsEnabled is set to false that the color used would be some derivative of TextColor, but it is not.

Comment: If there is no way to change the IsEnabled=False color, then I suppose I could use IsReadOnly=True instead though that is not available with the various Pickers.

Comment: If you have something to add to your question, [edit] the question rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a VisualState doing this and so I can edit that no problem.

```xml
<VisualStateGroupList>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateGroupList>
```